# Sum of a date range & match to sales region

Tags: excel, sum, match, sumifs

I want to Calculate the total Sales within a date range & within a sales region.

Have got `=SUMIF(C:C,E1,B:B)` to work out Total sales in a region.

& got this far in working out sales in a date range, but it returns a 0 value.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&H9,A:A,"<="&H11)
```

Would like help why its not working

But mostly would like to know is there a way to get the sum of a date range for the regions. put both sums together

Attached is an image of my data

[image: Sample of my data]

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure of the dates? The logic in your operand and the dates in column _H_ do not make sense. Could you please confirm and also which version of Excel are you running.

Comment: Phrase the series of conditions that need to be true for the sum, and use the `AND(<condition1>,<condition2>,...)` in your `SUMIF`. It has the huge benefit of making things much clearer and hence easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry Start date is 01/4/2015.

Comment: But it still gives me a 0 value? & im sorry FDavidov - im not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see in your data is, start date is greater than end date.
Ideally, Start date should be smaller than the end date.

In your data -

Start date - 01/04/**2016**
End date - 31/11/**2015**

Please check once.
Rest your formula is correct. and also, check the date formats once. make sure they are proper date formats not text or any custom formats.

Comment: Sorry Start date is 01/04/2015 & it was the format - Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Taupo -- `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A, ">="&H9, A:A, "<="&H11,C:C,E13)` - Got it worked out

The date format was incorrect

Thanks for all your help